# Famo.us : Is there a way to clear an "emit" emitted by a view?

Tags: famo.us, eventhandler

Currently trying to add multiple functions to a single surface. hoping there is something similar to "pipe" which is "unpipe" is there an "unemit"?

Comment: How do you unemit something once it's emitted? It doesn't make sense. For example, after you throw a ball, you can't unthrow it; it can't come back magically. What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can removeListener to get rid of the .on or .addListener so that even though the event is emitted it would no longer be acted on. You can also delete what is sending the emit and recreate it without although I don't see that you need to. Even if it never fires again who cares it doesn't take a lot of memory, why would you want it gone?